# Signing cookies in express

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

If I understood cookie signing correctly, then what it does is:
Sign a cookie with a secret when setting it.
Unsign the cookie with the same secret to validate that it hasn't been changed when recieving it.

Now in [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/) there is `res.cookie()` to set cookies and that takes a "signed" boolean to set if the cookie should be signed or not.

Now, what secret is used for signing? I think it might use the secret provided to `cookieParser()`, but that isn't actually mentioned explicitly in the documentation anywhere.

So my question is essentially: How do I set the secret to be used for signing cookies in expressjs?

I did read the express documentation and searched google and stackoverflow for an answers, sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Express will indeed use the secret provided to `cookie-parser` to sign your cookie. Cookie-parser will [inject the secret into your request object](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser/blob/master/index.js#L50). Then, express will [use it in order to sign the cookie](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L827). If no secret is provided to `cookie-parser` (or another middleware), then express will [throw an error](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L833) when trying to set a new signed cookie.

Answering your question, that's how you should set the secret (using `cookie-parser`):

```
var express = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser('your-secret'))

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.cookie('name', 'value', { signed: true })
  res.json({})
})
```

Then it will be available in `req.signedCookies`.

Answer (score 2):

This `cookieParser()` takes secret and option. For signed cookie, you can access through `req.signedCookies` and for unsigned cookies just `req.cookies`.
For sending cookies with response use cookie-like

```
app.use(cookieParser('12345'));
     res.cookie('username', 'john doe', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true, signed: true, secret: '12345' });
    res.cookie('user_name', 'anik islam', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true, signed: false, secret: '12345' });
```

And you can access cookies like

```
console.log(req.cookies);
console.log(req.signedCookies);
```